# Fetching form data to URL with JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I have a form in my html page and I added it to JS and now I want to fetch to a URL to add my data. This is my code:

The results from the form:

```
let password = document.getElementById("Password")
let Mail = document.getElementById("Mail")
let username = document.getElementById("Username")
```

Adding the results to an element

```
let data = {
        email: Mail,
        password: password,
        nickName: username
    }
```

Fetching to a link

```
fetch('The Link', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Credentials' : 'include',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(data),
 })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
         if (response === 200){
             return data.json();
         }
         else{
             throw 'error with server status';
         }
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         fout.appendChild(
             document.createTextNode(error));
     });
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @SiCK How I can fetch the data from my html page with JS to an URL

Answer (score 0):

Your status check should be in the preceding `then()` where the response object exists

```
fetch('The Link', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Credentials': 'include',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('error with server status');
    }
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    // consume the data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    fout.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(error.message));
  });
```

Comment: So what do I have to add in the .then(data => {.....}

Comment: That's where you process the array or object. If array something like `data.forEach(value=> /* do something with value*/)`

Comment: Okey sorry I'm a real beginner so I just don't understand...  this is the data I need to send =>   ` let data = {
           email: Mail,
            password: passwordV,
            nickName: username
        }`

Comment: No. The data in the then() is what was returned from server after you sent that

Comment: But the data isn't where it needs to come

Comment: No idea what that means. You probably need to study some `fetch()` or ajax tutorials

Comment: `.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('error with server status');
    }` if you throw like this without reading the response body chrome won't display error response in network tab (if there was any, like validation errors). This can confuse people while debugging.

Comment: @TJ I don't follow what you are suggesting. if your catch sees that error you know where it came from. what are you proposing? you can certainly pass on status and other meta . OP is very much a beginner

Comment: It's a special case with chrome. It'll probably get fixed in few versions from now. What I meant to say is if you throw like this, when you inspect the "network" tab in devtools, it won't show any response even if server actually sent a response